# Python: find previous and next `True` element in circular list

Tags: python

What is the best way to find the previous `True` element given current index in circular list.

For example given the data like these

```py
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
my_list_condition = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

1. Find the previous element

```py
before_e = find_prev('e', my_list, my_list_condition)
# before_e should be 'd'
before_c = find_prev('c', my_list, my_list_condition)
# before_c should be 'g' because it's circular list and the first True element before c is g
```

2. Find the next element

```py
after_e = find_next('e', my_list, my_list_condition)
# after_e should output 'f'

after_g = find_next('g', my_list, my_list_condition)
# after_g should output 'c' because it's circular list and the first True element after c is g
```

Comment: Iterate over the string, and reset index to 0 once it exceeds `len(my_list)-1` Also can you provide some code you tried for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `itertools.cycle` And `itertools.compress` to find the next element ensuring circular looping and only looping needed items but ensure the element in conditions is kept, once that’s done, then finding the previous is just finding the next in reverse:

```
from itertools import cycle, compress

def find_next(c, lst, lst_condition):
    condition = lst_condition[:]
    condition[lst.index(c)] = 1
    elems = cycle(compress(lst, condition))
    for elem in elems:
        if elem == c:
            return next(elems)

def find_prev(c, lst, lst_condition):
    return find_next(c, list(reversed(lst)), list(reversed(lst_condition)))
```

Test:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
my_list_condition = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]

find_prev('e', my_list, my_list_condition) #d
find_prev('c', my_list, my_list_condition) #g

find_next('e', my_list, my_list_condition) # f
find_next('g', my_list, my_list_condition) #c
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jab. Really love your solution

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

```
from functools import partial

my_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
my_list_condition = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]


def find_next(element, element_list, condition_list, backward=False):
    step = -1 if backward else 1
    next_index = element_list.index(element) + step
    length = len(element_list)
    while True:
        if next_index < 0 or next_index >= length:
            next_index = (next_index + length) % length
        if condition_list[next_index]:
            return element_list[next_index]
        next_index += step


find_prev = partial(find_next, backward=True)

print(find_prev("e", my_list, my_list_condition))
# d
print(find_prev("c", my_list, my_list_condition))
# g
print(find_next("e", my_list, my_list_condition))
# f
print(find_next("g", my_list, my_list_condition))
# c
```